# C++ find all files of type in folder?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to list all the files of a certain type in a folder, so that I can loop through them. This should be simple, surely, but I can't get it.
I have found some example using dirent.h, but I need to do this in straight c++.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't the canonical dirent example work for you?

Comment: I will be using this inside unreal engine, and would like to avoid using third party headers if i can.

Comment: I always chuckle when someone considers "using third-party headers" to **not** be "straight C++". ;-)

Comment: Why these down- and close-votes ? The question is reasonably well asked, research has been done, and listing files in a folder is in no way "too broad". Coming from one of the numerous other languages that provide filesystem functionality out-of-the-box, this is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: @Quentin : I did not downvote (the question is currently at 0 and I find it acceptable) but I do not know what is a *straight c++* way of reading directories. `dirent.h` is a standard Posix header. If OP meant winapi or anything else, it should say it, but *straight c++* does not mean anything.

Comment: @SergeBallesta "straight" ("plain", "vanilla", etc) C++ is just C++ and its standard library. And the answer is, there's no standard way of accessing a filesystem in C++. For example, the same question about Java would have brought up `java.io.File`.

Comment: @Quentin : you said it better than I did. But as neither C++ standard library, nor C standard library has a portable way to read directories there is no plain C++ way to do it. That's why I thought that OP wanted a way dedicated to an underlying system but with no third party library

Answer (score 6):

You *cannot* do this in "straight C++", because C++ does not have a filesystem API [yet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs).

I'd traditionally recommend Boost.Filesystem here, but you allegedly want to "avoid using third party headers if [you] can".

So your best bet is to use POSIX *dirent.h*, as you have been doing all along. It's about as "non-third party" as you're going to get for the time being.

Comment: If you are using Unreal engine, try to find file manipulation functions there. I don't think someone would make a full-blown game engine without it being able to read files ;)

Comment: Nice info under that *yet*! At least it will alleviate OP's worries about getiing his C++ straightened out.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?  This finds all suid files in folders you specify, but can be modified to find any number of things, or use a regex for the extension if that is what you mean by 'type'.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <vector>


bool is_suid(const char *file)
{
  struct stat results;
  stat(file, &results);
  if (results.st_mode & S_ISUID) return true;
  return false;
}


void help_me(char *me) {
  std::cout
  << "Usage:" << std::endl
  << " " << me << " /bin/ /usr/sbin/ /usr/bin/ /usr/bin/libexec/" << std::endl;
  exit(1);  
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2) help_me(argv[0]);
  std::string file_str;
  std::vector<std::string> file_list;
  for (int path_num = 1; path_num != argc; path_num++) {
    const char * path = argv[path_num];
    DIR *the_dir;
    struct dirent *this_dir;
    the_dir = opendir(path);
    if (the_dir != NULL) while (this_dir = readdir(the_dir)) file_list.push_back(std::string(this_dir->d_name));
    std::string name;
    for(int file_num = 0; file_num != file_list.size(); file_num++) {
      name = file_list[file_num];
      std::string path_to_file = std::string(path) + file_list[file_num];
      if (is_suid(path_to_file.c_str()) == true) std::cout << path_to_file << std::endl;
    }
    file_list.clear();
    file_list.shrink_to_fit();
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This is literally what the OP asked to avoid. I feel like perhaps you didn't read all of the question.

Comment: You're correct, I saw the avoiding dirent after I posted.